# Is it possible to get png/csv file directly from neo4j browser?

Tags: neo4j

I want to save either the png or csv file, which could be done manually by accessing the browser page, but with javascript or curl? I seem to can't have it done, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Neo4j Desktop and the browser interface has a icon in the upper right of the results to download a CSV.